# Lenovo G40-45 AMD Driver match for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, ati, brightness, lenovo, battery

I have Lenovo G40-45 Laptop with specs :

- AMD A8-6410 Processor
- Radeon R5 M230

I use Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 LTS for the operating system, overall almost my laptop work properly with Ubuntu, but I found an issue with my laptop :

1. I can't adjust the brightness in my laptop with the shortcut keys or setting the brightness otherwise
2. I think my battery is draining faster than my other OS (Windows 8.1) and also I think my laptop is overheating with Ubuntu, whereas it's not problem in Windows 8.1

I originally had the same issue adjusting brightness in Windows 8.1 too, but I solved that with installing an AMD driver for Windows [here](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/g40-45-notebook-lenovo?c=1)

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same model of Lenovo laptop. I achieved the battery life last longer with this guide in Spanish. The battery have the same performance than Windows 8.
http://www.taringa.net/posts/linux/18073964/Optimizacion-de-energia-Dell-Inspirion-5521.html

Comment: I've seen the link, above. at a glance, i think that's can solve my issue. But when i read more, i completely can't understand the spanish language. So do you have another links similiar with english? But Thank's anyway @Jorge

Comment: You try to use google traslator? I have an image about linuxmint 17.1 if you want I can share it by ftp.

Comment: hmmm i think, i'll use google translate. although i'm not sure i'll get the point. Thank's anyway